# How to search for two question marks("??") in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, find-and-replace

As the title suggests, I need to find and replace two consecutive question marks (`??`) in my Excel file.

I've tried the solution at: [How to search for ? (question mark) in Excel](https://superuser.com/questions/458606/how-to-search-for-question-mark-in-excel) . I tried with `~??` but this also replaces single question marks (`?`)...

How would I go about it??

Comment: Did you try ~?~?

Comment: Instead of ~?? try ~?~?. I think that will fix your issue.

Comment: Oh...right. That fixed it. How stupid. Thanks guys, post it as answer and I'll accept & upvote it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ~?~? instead.

The ~ escapes the question mark, telling Excel that you don't want it to use the question mark to represent any letter (see "[wildcards in Excel](http://www.exceluser.com/excel_help/functions/guide-to-excel-wildcards.htm)" for example)

[image]