# Excel search for ~* or ~? sequence

Tags: microsoft-excel, search, find-and-replace, wildcards

A previous question (link below) concerns how to search for the star and question mark characters in Excel. This can be done by entering ~* or ~? in the 'Find What' field. My question, then, is how does one search for the string ~* or ~? ?

[How to search for ? (question mark) in Excel](https://superuser.com/questions/458606/how-to-search-for-question-mark-in-excel)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`~` is a special character, so it need to be skipped too.

Type `~~~*` to look for `~*`
Type `~~~?` to look for `~?`