# Excel: How to ignore wildcards in COUNTIF

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016

I'm trying to write a function that counts duplicate entries in a character column.
**(See column function in image below)**

However, the function reports incorrect information for some characters.
For example, the character `<` doesn't count at all, and the character `*` counts everything.

Is there a way to force excel to count characters literally, and ignore all special behavior?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an alternative to **COUNTIF**:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(N(CODE([Character])=CODE([@Character])))
```

The logic of this formula is searching code of character instead of character itself.

Also here is an article on why I used the **SUMPRODUCT** function: [How to count values by length](https://www.spreadsheetweb.com/how-to-count-values-by-length/)

Answer (score 1):

Since the key issue is, "**I'm trying to write a function that counts duplicate entries in a character column**".

Write this formula in **Cell B2** and fill it downwards:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(LEN($A$2:$A$12)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE($A$2:$A$12,A2,"")))
```

*Check the screen shot:*

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want COUNTIF to handle a literal `*`, then search for it as `~*` as explained [here](https://superuser.com/a/521794/261107).
To search for a literal `<` (less than) symbol, search for it as `=<` as demonstrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19035772/1898524).

To get them to work in your COUNTIF formula, use the `SUBSTITUTE()` function.

```c#
=COUNTIF([Character],SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE([@Character],"*","~*"),"<","=<"))
```